# Tableau: how to align text in dual axis-ed column labels

Tags: tableau-api

I am having trouble with label's text alignment. I used workaround to have rows coloured based on a value of certain row (featured in e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JK_Y1B8eGU)); for example, if the Status is "Cancelled", it colours entire row red, otherwise it is green.

I created `AGG(MAX(1))` columns for bar (with fixed range 0 to 1) and `AGG(MAX(0))` columns for text (with fixed range 0 to 0), then paired them through dual axis.

However, I found out the text label is automatically aligned to the centre. I looked into text label options and set my alignment to the left (in both *Edit Label* window and *Alignment* setting) but it had no effect whatsoever. I changed *Format...* settings for column but once again, it had no effect.

I even tried changing fixed range on `AGG(MAX(0))` columns or changing the zero in `MAX(0)` to some other number but this only moved centre-aligned text so it was of no use.

Here is a picture to illustrate my point:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the issue and also arrived at better way to do it than the one I described in my question.

Here's the tutorial (using Tableau 2021.4):

1. Create a column `MAX(-1)`. Right-click the column, go to *Edit Axis...*, set Range to fixed (start at -1, end at 0), delete the Title, and disable all Tick Marks (by setting them to 'None').
2. In Marks panel, set the Mark to 'Gantt Bar'.
3. Drop your condition for coloring (e.g. calculated field) on Color in Marks panel.
4. Create a calculated field `MAX(1)` and drop it on Size in Marks panel. This will fill out entire column width with a color bar. If needed, increase the bar width by moving the slider under Size to the right.
5. Drop the text value on Label in Marks panel. Now you should see text labels. If not, increase cell's height (*Format > Cell Size > Taller* or Ctrl+Up).
6. If you want a header (just like shown in my picture), create a column `MAX(0)`, set its Range to fixed (start at 0, end at 0), disable all Tick Marks and change the Title.
7. Right-click the `MAX(0)` and tick 'Dual Axis'.

In case you'll encounter some challenges when formatting the end result, check formatting hierarchy ([this tutorial](https://youtu.be/0pursdur27A?t=581) may help).